# My text turns bold when editing it in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

When I edit text in Photoshop it seems to add an extra bit of weight around the characters - it goes back to normal when I'm not directly editing text.

What's going on here?

[[image: font issue]]

Click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klybo.png)

Comment: Traditionally anti-aliasing is disabled while editing. But I've never seen type vary *that* much. Shouldn't really matter though if it only happens while editing the text.

Comment: That is quite bizarre and i haven't experienced that before. Could you share a screenshot that includes the layers so we can see if there's any sort of layer effects or masking that might be bugging photoshop out? It is also possible that the font might be messed up somehow, does it happen with all fonts you use?

Comment: Does this only happen with this single font? Does this also happen on computers with different graphic cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, feel like a bit of an idiot now!

Turns out I had 'Faux Bold' toggled!

All fixed now, thanks for the suggestions though.